# Optimal way to create test requests for Python (Django) REST APIs

Tags: python, django, api, testing, automated-tests

I have an API/microservice written in Django which is computational in nature. Depending on the request parameters, the API does some computations and gives an output. I need to test the API by simulating various possible combinations of requests and corresponding responses.

A few points to consider about my API:

1. The request consists of around 20 parameters. Each parameter can be of different type, for eg. binary, lists, dictionary, etc. Based on the whole input request, the API does some computation which I need to test. Example of a dummy request with just 3 params:

> {
> param1: True/False,
> param2: *list of strings*
> param3: *list of dictionaries*
> }

2. Each combination of parameter gives a different output. For example in the above request with 3 params, I can have 2 scenarios to test - by putting param1 as True and False. Similarly I can pass various strings in param2 list ( I have predefined set of eligible strings) and so on. Thus with around 20-25 parameters, I have a lot of requests possible with different combinations of parameters taken at a time.

Currently I am storing each request in a file by manually creating the request for various combinations possible. Then I am writing test cases for each request by defining the expected output. This approach is not efficient for testing the API. Moreover if I change even a single parameter in future or add an extra parameter, I will have to manually edit all requests to make them up to date.

I have explored various testing frameworks but none of them seem to address my problem of creating various possible request combinations. Please suggest some better way to test these kind of APIs with various request combinations.

Is there no better way than writing script to generate the request?

Answer (score 0):

You could use combinations in the itertools to generate the possible combinations
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations